# Construction of Lebesgue measure on manifolds without smooth structure

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds

How would you define a "relatively natural" measure on a manifold without smooth structure?

I have read here that the "standard" way to find a Lebesgue measure on a smooth (compact? orientable?) manifold is to choose a Riemannian metric.  This gives you a volume form on each chart and the coordinate changes are compatible with these local volume forms.  You can then define a linear form on continuous functions which allows you to use the Riesz representation theorem.

What can you do if you don't have a smooth structure on $M$?  The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is well-defined.  I guess if the manifold is compact, you could select a finite collection of charts $(U_1,\phi_1),\dotsc,(U_N,\phi_N)$ covering the manifold.  Take a compact subset $K_j\subset U_j$ such that $\cup_j K_j$ still covers $M$. Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and define for each chart $U_j$ a measure $\mu_j$ on $M$ by
$$\mu_j(A) :=\lambda(\phi_j(A\cap K_j)) $$
for every Borel set $A$.

Then define a measure $\mu := \sum_j \mu_j$.  After this you can do the completion of $\mu$.

Does this work?  Does this work if $M$ is non-compact?

I have the impression that I am not using he Riesz theorem, and that I also do not need the manifold to be orientable ?  Am I cheating (to myself)?  Is this equivalent to the other construction (in the sense that for compact manifolds the respective $L^p$-functions are the same)?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by natural. What makes the Riemannian volume form natural is that it respect an additional structure, which is the Riemannian structure. If one considers another kind of additional structure, such as the action of some group, another volume form will be natural to consider (an invariant one for instance). Without another layer of structure, I wouldn't say what is natural!

Comment: Also, what you defined works, but highly depends on the choice of charts you have made: this is because you are considering pull-back measures on the charts, which indeed define measures on $M$, and because the set of measures is a cone. This also works if you consider an open cover on a non-compact manifold which is locally finite

Comment: In dimensions different from 4 you can use the existence of a bilipschitz atlas on a topological manifold (Sullivan's theorem). I do not know if you will find it natural though. It is known that any two such measures will be volume-isomorphic via some homeomorphism as long as total volumes are the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no such measure, in the sense that nontrivial manifolds do not admit any measure whatsoever which is invariant under the diffeomorphism group (this would be a precise definition of "natural," or at least a requirement any such definition should satisfy). As Didier says in the comments, your construction depends crucially on a choice of charts.

Comment: I meant natural in an intuitive sense.  Of course you could always choose the null-measure or a delta measure for a point or something like this, but I would like a measure that behaves like ... "like a Lebesgue measure on $R^n$". Whatever that means.

Comment: @KlausNiederkrüger: something like your construction probably works, then, but what do you want to use it for?

Comment: Nothing particular, just trying to understand what I really need, and what I can get.   There are manifolds that do not admit any smooth structure, and manifolds that admit non-diffeomorphic smooth structures.  I have the impression that for compact manifolds the $L^p$ spaces really only depend on the topology (in the sense the the identify would be an isomorphism).  For non-compact smooth manifolds, things are of course different as one can see from regarding $]-1,1[$ and $\mathbb R$ which are diffeomorphic but lead to different $L^p$.

Comment: @KlausNiederkrüger: I don't know what you mean by "different $L^p$" in that last sentence. Of course because those manifolds are diffeomorphic I can take any measure on one of them and transport it to the other, and the corresponding $L^p$ spaces are isometric. You presumably have in mind a specific choice of such measures, namely the Lebesgue measures, but how do you plan on singling out this specific measure among all such measures?

Comment: Maybe the proper question, I wanted to ask was:  Is there a natural way to define $L^p$-spaces on a $C^0$-manifold.  "Natural" would mean for all choices, the underlying set of functions in $L^p$ agrees and the respective $L^p$-norms are equivalent.

Comment: There are no diffeomorphisms without a smooth structure.  Now you could say, let's take one, but as I said many topological manifolds do not admit any, and some topological manifolds do admit several ones (that are not diffeomorphic).

But I might hope that if I construct one measure $\mu_1$ for a certain choice of charts etc and a second one $\mu_2$ for other choices, then every function that is $L^p$ with respect to $\mu_1$ is also $L^p$ with respect to $\mu_2$, and moreover the identity map between these two spaces is bounded in both directions.

Comment: Maybe a different way to try to define "natural" would be that there is a Radon Nikodym function for any two measures constructed this way such that the function is bounded and does not vanish anywhere (probably this is too weak).

Comment: @KlausNiederkrüger: on a compact manifold I think some variation of your construction will get you this. On a noncompact manifold I don't think you can expect a unique $L^p$ space.

Comment: What makes the Lebesgue measure "natural" on $\Bbb R^n$ is that it is invariant under translation and scales exactly as the homotheties. These considerations being meaningless on a manifold, we cannot find such a "natural" measure there. Regarding $L^p$ spaces, I agree with Qiaochu Yuan: this appears to me hopeless to look for a uniqueness statement on a non compact manifold